# Disable hot corner in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, unity

Taking mouse to top left corner opens activities. How to remove it in the desktop of Ubuntu 18.04? How to disable it?

Answer (score 2):

Install GNOME Tweaks if you haven't already:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Open Tweaks → *Top Bar* and turn off *Activities Overview Hot Corner*.

Comment: Activitues Overview Hot Corner was already set to "off" when I opened up Tweaks. I had to flick the switch to "on" and back to "off" for the hot corner to disable.